# Escaping characters for instance query matching in webpy

Tags: python, regex, sqlite, python-2.7, web.py

(The title may be in error here, but I believe that the problem is related to escaping characters)

I'm using webpy to create a VERY simple todo list using peewee with Sqlite to store simple, user submitted todo list items, such as "do my taxes" or "don't forget to interact with people", etc.

What I've noticed is that the DELETE request fails on certain inputs that contain specific symbols. For example, while I can add the following entries to my Sqlite database that contains all the user input, I cannot DELETE them:

```
what?
test#
test & test 
This is a test?
```

Any other user input with any other symbols I'm able to DELETE with no issues. Here's the webpy error message I get in the browser when I try to DELETE the inputs list above:

```
<class 'peewee.UserInfoDoesNotExist'> at /del/test
Instance matching query does not exist: SQL: SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."title" FROM "userinfo" AS t1 WHERE ("t1"."title" = ?) PARAMS: [u'test']
Python  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py in get, line 2598
Web     POST http://0.0.0.0:7700/del/test
```

When I view the database file (called `todoUserList.db`) in sqlitebrowser, I can see that these entries do exist with the symbols, they're all there. 
[image]

In my main webpy app script, I'm using a regex to search through the db to make a DELETE request, it looks like this:

```
urls = (
    '/', 'Index',
    '/del/(.*?)', 'Delete'
)
```

I've tried variations of the regex, such as `'/del/(.*)'`, but still get the same error, so I don't think that's the problem.

Given the error message above, is webpy not "seeing" certain symbols in the user input because they're not being escaped properly?

Confused as to why it seems to only happen with the select symbols listed above.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I've tried that and get the same error I included above, that looks like: `<class 'peewee.UserInfoDoesNotExist'> at /del/Does this work
Instance matching query does not exist: SQL: SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."title" FROM "userinfo" AS t1 WHERE ("t1"."title" = ?) PARAMS: [u'Does this work']`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the URL escaping is functioning it could be an issue in particular with how "?" and "&" are interpreted by the browser (in a typical GET style request & and ? are special character used to separate query [string parameters](https://perishablepress.com/how-to-write-valid-url-query-string-parameters/))

Comment: thanks Jon, is there a way to "protect" the user input string from losing those characters/symbols?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing those in as part of the URL itself you should pass them in as an escaped querystring. As far as I know, no web server is going to respect wacky values like that as part of a URL. If they are escaped and put in the querystring (or `POST` body) you'll be fine, though.